# BaseExpandableListAdapter is not called

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

In this class

```
   public class Rest_name_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {
   }
```

I have put Logs in all the methods to check the sequence of called methods. But from the statement in my activity class

```
   exp_listView.setAdpater(new Rest_name_adapter(getParent(), group_list, child_list));
```

It goes to the Rest_name_adapter class, just calls the contructor and nothing else. I dont know why It is not calling this: `getChildView()` and `getGroupView()` methods?? In context, I have used `getParent()` because this is the child of `TabGroupActivity`.  Please help

Comment: try `this.getParent()` it may help you.

Comment: what is the size of your data sets? are you returning proper count of child and groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you implement some methods in your Rest_name_adapter?
If not there is a simple explanation - adapter calls getGroupCount(), which returns 0 by default. 
As there a no groups - no views needed. So there is no one call to getGroupView() occured.